# JREPL.BAT - Having issues with /INC and a string with a unicode symbol

Tags: jrepl

I have a string that i'm using as a [START] position within a /INC. This string has a unicode symbol.

This unicode symbol appears to NOT be getting read by JREPL. My output file ends up blank until I remove the symbol and retry.

Is there any way around this with JREPL?

!REFID_NAME_STRING!

Buzz!™ 100 Questions Correct T-shirt

```
CALL JREPL "(.*)" "$txt=$1" /I /XSEQ /JMATCHQ /INC "'<LANG ID=\qREF\q>!REFID_NAME_STRING!</LANG>':'</PHRASE>'" /EXC "'</PHRASE>','<LANG ID=\qREF\q>'" /F "%SRC1%!SRCFOLDER!\!PTH!\!UUID!\LOCALTEMP\LOCALISATION.XML"  /O "%SRC1%!SRCFOLDER!\!PTH!\!UUID!\LOCALTEMP\NAME_ALL.LOCAL"
```